# Remove subfolder from URL if the next subfolder is a specified subfolder (.htaccess)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

For example:

This is fine: `http://example.com/ecommerce/`

This is also fine: `http://example.com/ecommerce/another-sub/`

But if the subfolder after *ecommerce* is *seo*, **remove** *ecommerce*:

This is not fine: `http://example.com/ecommerce/seo/` and should be redirected to `http://example.com/seo/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is no .htaccess in `ecommerce/`, you can use this rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^ecommerce/(seo)(/.*)?$ /$1$2 [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: That's awesome. Is there a way of removing `seo` only if it's directly proceeding `ecommerce`? Currently, it's removing `ecommerce` if the `seo` subfolder is anywhere in the URL.

Comment: ok try this rule: `RewriteRule ^ecommerce/(seo)(/(?!.*seo).*)?$ /$1$2 [L,NC,R=302]`